# SQL join multiple values from column into one cell

Tags: sql, mysql, join, left-join

There are a ton of SQL `JOIN` questions already, but I didn't see my answer so here it goes.

I am working with MySQL 5.0 and Wordpress Database using helper classes [wpdb](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/) and [ezsql](https://github.com/ezSQL/ezsql). Trying to achieve the 'simple' desired output below has not proven to be easy.

Current output:

```
MemberID          MemberName              FruitName
--------------    ---------------------   --------------
1                  Al                     Apple
1                  Al                     Cherry
```

Desired output:

```
MemberID           MemberName            FruitName
-----------        --------------        ------------
1                  Al                    Apple, Cherry
```

`MemberID` comes from the table `a`, `MemberName` comes from the tables `a` and `b`, and `FruitName` comes from the table `b`. Because I am outputting a lot of other columns from the table `a`, I have 'left joined' the two tables through this query:

```
$contents = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.MemberName = b.MemberName"));
```

I later print the columns using echo:

```
        <td><?php echo $content->MemberID ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $content->MemberName ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $content->FruitName ?></td>
```

I assume I should try to query/join the two tables in a different manner though it may be possible to get creative in printing the columns. I found this [discussion here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/conversation.aspx?messageid=34132286&threadid=34132286) and modeled my question after it but I don't understand their solutions and am hoping for something simpler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GROUP BY MemberName and GROUP_CONCAT(FruitName). For example,

```
SELECT MemberId, MemberName, GROUP_CONCAT(FruitName) FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.MemberName = b.MemberName GROUP BY a.MemberName;
```

Comment: Hmm, tried this out and got an error that said that MemberName is an ambiguous field so I changed SELECT MemberID, MemberName to SELECT MemberID, a.MemberName and my out put looked like this:

MemberID        MemberName      GROUP_CONCAT(FruitName)
1                  Al              [BLOB - 3 B]   <-concatenating
2                  A2              [BLOB - NULL]
3                  A3              [BLOB - NULL]

Comment: I tried to simplify the question and ended up not getting the answer that tied directly to my working db.  So I created the tables as I demonstrated here and got it to work...one problem: the group_concat function pulls each fruit twice! I will start a new question as Google is fruitless (no pun intended).  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Given that you're using MySQL, I believe one of the [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) function (one of the available [*aggregate functions*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions-and-modifiers.html)) will do exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT MemberID, MemberName, GROUP_CONCAT(FruitName SEPARATOR ',') FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.MemberName = b.MemberName GROUP BY MemberID, MemberName;
```

Comment: had the exact same problem as below

Answer (score 0):

One way is to loop and build the output in PHP (or whatever language yo are using).

Either concatenate the fruits when fetching the rows from db, or when presenting it to the user. Id suggest the latter, since it's more of a view-logic issue than anything else.

If you want to do it in SQL you'll either have to create your own (I do not belive MySQL has it built in, but I might be wrong) aggregate function to concatenate strings. It is not so trivial.

If you are fetching only one member, you can also do it in SQL by using a variable, Im  uncertaing about the exact MySQL syntax, but for MSSQL it would be something like:

```
DECLARE @frutis VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @fruits = ISNULL(@fruits + ', ' + FruitName, FruitName)
FROM ... 

SELECT @fruits
```

Answer (score 0):

@Adam
I know it might be late to answer but I just ran into the same issue, so here's my solution to extend Mike answer and solve the multiple same fruit occurences:

```
SELECT MemberId, MemberName, GROUP_CONCAT(distinct FruitName) FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.MemberName = b.MemberName GROUP BY a.MemberName;
```

So basically you just need to add "distinct" in the GROUP_CONCAT function.

I hope that helps.